# Setup Qt5 via CMake FetchContent

Tags: cmake, qt5

I`m trying to download and setup Qt5 version 5.13 via the CMake`FetchContent` module. Unfortunately the

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 Win64" ..\mytestapp
```

call hangs. Last line of output to the command line is:

```
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
```

In my build directory, I can see the `_deps` folder with a qt5-build, qt5-src and qt5-subbuild folder. The qt5-build folder is empty. Both the qt5-src and qt5-subbuild folder has some files and folders.

This is my current CMakeLists.txt file for the Qt download and setup.

```
include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
  qt5
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git
  GIT_TAG        5.13
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(qt5)
if(NOT qt5_POPULATED)
   FetchContent_Populate(qt5)
  add_subdirectory(${qt5_SOURCE_DIR} ${qt5_BINARY_DIR})
endif()

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets REQUIRED)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the background it clones the Qt repo, which is GBs in size. You probably just have to wait longer.

Edit: after trying this myself,  https://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git does not have a cmake build script, so you would have to execute `./configure` and other things to actually build it. Probably FetchContent is not meant for this.